# Dynamic Site Address in HTTP request to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate, flow, powerapp

I'm working on app that is giving SharePoint Users Groups as a result. Finally I finished almost everything - the last condition I have to complete is dynamic site address, so my app and flow could be used in more than one website.

Currently my HTTP request looks like this:

[image]

What should I type in `Site Address` section to make it dynamic?

Comment: It depends on how you want to pass the dynamic value to flow: 1. Pass value from app to flow using flow inputs 2. Use environment variables.

Comment: Users don't have to provide any inputs (only click the button in powerapp) so I think it should be an environment variable?

Comment: You can create a variable inside a power app with site URL & pass it to the flow as an input while running the flow.

Comment: I'm not sure how to make it. Should I add another step to my flow using `Initialize variable` and pass it before `PowerApps(V2)` step in flow?

Comment: Check my answer given below. hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can add one more flow input in PowerApps (V2) trigger like:

[image]

Then use this input in HTTP request action from dynamic content:

1. Click in Site address dropdown & any random text (example: xyz) and click on "Enter custom value":

   [image]
2. Select siteAddress input from dynamic content:

   [image]

---

In Power apps change the formula where you are running the flow like:

```
Set(userGroupNamesString, FlowName.Run(User().Email, "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/work").usergroupnames);
```

In 2nd parameter, pass the site address.

---

**Update from comments**:

Use formula like below:

```
Set(
    userGroupNames;
    GroupRetrieveByEmail.Run(User().Email; "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/work").usergroupnames
);;
```

Comment: So my actual formula in OnSelect looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/Q0TY8Cp.png so after GroupRetrieveByEmail.Run(User().Email should i type siteAddress?

Comment: Yes, check updated answer for formula.

Comment: I used formula as you show above, but there is some syntax error
`Set(userGroupNames;GroupRetrieveByEmail.Run(User().Email); "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/work").usergroupnames);;`

"Invalid argument amount: received 3, expected: 2"

Comment: Can you use the same formula I gave (copy-paste the same)? In your above comment there is `)` extra after `User().Email`. Also, replace the site URL as per your actual site URL.

Comment: I already copy-paste same formula as you provide: https://i.imgur.com/9zgWyK4.png

i add second semicolon after `User().Email` but after running app it now doesn't display any groups

Comment: Did you add one more input in your flow? After adding input in flow & save, refresh the flow added in app OR remove & re-add the flow in your app.

Comment: Hi @Yarensky, is this problem solved or you still need help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable in your Power Automate flow and then use that variable for the site address value.